# Rounding up Dependencies for PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, cups

I have been trying to get a program I wrote in PyQt to work being called from a CUPS backend on OS X.
The problem is that CUPS sandboxing keeps the program from being able to access the PyQt python modules which I have brewed in /usr/local/Cellar.

Is there any way to grab those files, as well as the Qt files in the Cellar, and put them all in one contained folder?
It is simple for other modules, but PyQt depends on a lot itself.

I tried using pyinstaller and cx_freeze, but with no luck.

How can I round up all my applications dependencies into one location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the CUPS sandboxing by having the backend send the information to a listening server on localhost that then processed the job as I needed it. I made sure that the server listening would only accept connections from localhost.

I never was able to get pyinstaller or cx_freeze to work with PyQt, but this workaround was a better alternative.